# Is it possible to get a raw deflate out of java.util.zip.Deflater?

Tags: java, zlib

The [zlib docs](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) specify that one can pass a negative `windowBits` argument to the `deflateInit2()` function:

> `windowBits` can also be –8..–15 for raw *deflate*. In this case, `-windowBits`
>   determines the window size. `deflate()` will then generate raw `deflate` data
>   with no *zlib* header or trailer, and will not compute an adler32 check value.

I've used this in my C code, and in Java am able to inflate bytes thus compressed by passing `true` for the `nowrap` parameter to the [Inflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) constructor.

However, passing `true` for the `nowrap` parameter to the [Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) does not yield a raw deflate. It returns 20 more bytes than I get with my C implementation, which sure sounds like a header and checksum. (Passing `false` for `nowrap` yields an even longer byte array.)

I've scanned through the 
[Deflater docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) but have not found a way to specify window bits or that I want a raw deflate. Is it possible with this library? Or would I need to use some other implementation to get a raw deflate in Java?

Comment: AFAIK, passing true for the no-wrap parameter is the only way to use raw deflate.

Comment: I *think* passing `true` to the `nowrap` parameter yields an [RFC-1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) ZLIB result. Passing `false` yields an [RFC-1952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) Gzip result. What I want is an [RFC-1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) raw DEFLATE result.

Comment: have you looked at `DeflaterOutputStream` and `DeflaterInputStream` possibilities ? Perhaps that would help you.

Comment: Yes. It appears you pass an `Inflater` or `Deflater` object to their constructors, where all the zip-based attributes are set, not on the stream objects, AFAICT.

Comment: Then I must say I'm sorry, but I can't try to help you furthermore. My knowledge of `java.util.zip` is limited. This is obviously something I should work on more. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Deflater` produces zlib-wrapped data (RFC 1950).  `Deflater(level, true)` produces raw deflate data (RFC 1951).

Comment: Hrm. Why would it be 20 bytes longer than the output from the C implementation, then?

Comment: Different compressor settings?  Different compressor code?  If you provide the first 30 or so bytes in hex, I can verify if there is a wrapper or not.

Comment: First 30 Bytes deflated in C: `6D52CB729B3014FD95EE531349084974260BBD3018830101356C327E24A91`. I inflated them in Java then deflated them again with `Deflater(DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true)` and got bytes starting with `ED524D739B3014EC4FC9BD3591849044677290903018830101355C32FE485`.

Comment: Those are both raw deflate streams with no header.

Comment: Hrm. Any idea why the one from Java is 19 bytes longer?

Comment: I already gave you some theories.  You are either using different settings for the same compression code, or different compression code.